# Guardar el contenido de un .txt en un char* en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un programa que funciona con una variable **char* palabra = "Texto"** pero quiero obtener el valor de la variable de un archivo *txt*

Hola.txt

```
Hola mundo!
```

Adios.txt

```
Adios mundo!
```

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
Archivo.open(archivo);
if(!Archivo.fail()){
    char* palabra;
    // Guardar el contenido del archivo en la variable
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te recomendaría que usaras [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/), luego puedes crear un `streambuf` iterator del archivo e inicializar el string con ese valor:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::ifstream t("file.txt");
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    const char *cstr = str.c_str();
    std::cout<<cstr<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora tienes el `char*` en `cstr`

Comment: Tengo que usar char* y no string.

Comment: ok actualizé la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto soluciona mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy sencillo leer datos de un archivo usando `ifstream` y [`std::getline`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), lo que no es sencillo (y no tiene mucho sentido) es leer en un `char *`.

El tener los datos de texto en un puntero implica que el programador debe hacerse cargo de la gestión de dicho puntero, siendo esto propenso a errores.

#### Leer una linea en un puntero a caracter... mala idea.

```
char *lee_de_archivo(const std::string nombre)
{
    std::ifstream archivo(nombre);
    std::string linea{};

    if (std::getline(archivo, linea))
    {
        char *resultado = new char[linea.size() + 1];
        std::copy(linea.begin(), linea.end(), resultado);
        resultado[linea.size()] = 0;
        return resultado;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Esta función obtiene el texto del archivo pero el programador debe encargarse de liberar la memoria solicitada tras su uso:

```
char *palabra = lee_de_archivo("Hola.txt");
delete [] palabra;
```

De no hacerlo, se produciría una [fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria), como en los siguientes ejemplos:

```
std::cout << lee_de_archivo("Hola.txt") << '\n';
std::string mensaje = std::string("Mensaje: ") + lee_de_archivo("Hola.txt");
std::copy(lee_de_archivo("Hola.txt"), lee_de_archivo("Hola.txt") + 10, ptr);
```

En especial la última línea es nefasta porque ademas de fugas de memoria provocaría accesos inválidos a memoria ya que el retorno de `lee_de_archivo` devuelve punteros diferentes en cada llamada.

#### ¿Por qué no acceder al puntero interno de un `std::string`?

En la propuesta de [eLRuLL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40484/2742) se accede al puntero interno de un objeto `std::string` mediante el método [`c_str`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) y esto también puede ser problemático, podemos verlo adaptando la función `lee_de_archivo`:

```
char *lee_de_archivo(const std::string nombre)
{
    std::ifstream archivo(nombre);
    std::string linea{};

    if (std::getline(archivo, linea))
    {
        return linea.c_str();
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

En el momento en que salimos de la función `lee_de_archivo` el objeto `linea` que nos proporciona el puntero a la cadena deja de existir, y en consecuencia los datos apuntados dejan de ser válidos.

El código de [eLRuLL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26160/elrull) no tiene ese problema ya que el ciclo de vida del `std::string` y del puntero a los datos internos del mismo coincide, pero se considera mala práctica romper la [encapsulación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) guardando punteros o referencias a datos internos de un objeto.

> #### Tengo que usar char* y no string. – [akko](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4676/akko)

Es una limitación sin sentido en C++ moderno. La tendencia actual es que los punteros rasos caigan en desuso siendo substituidos por [punteros inteligentes](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) u otros objetos que manejen el ciclo de vida de la memoria dinámica.

Mi consejo es que olvides esa limitación y uses `std::string` que da menos problemas:

```
std::string lee_de_archivo(const std::string nombre)
{
    std::ifstream archivo(nombre);
    std::string linea{};
    std::getline(archivo, linea);

    return linea;
}
```